# Wordpress 4.x - Best plugin for responsive version

Tags: wordpress, mobile, plugins, responsive-design

I'm searching a good plugin for activate the mobile version of my wp 4.1  blog.

Which is the best plugin for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather suggest you installing responsive theme instead using plugin for that. Here you go - fresh Responsive Wordpress Themes. Some are free some are paid:

**Top 10 Best Free Responsive Premium WordPress Themes for 2015**
http://www.designbolts.com/2014/12/17/top-10-best-free-responsive-premium-wordpress-themes-for-2015/

**30+ Best Responsive WordPress Portfolio Themes 2015**
http://www.designmaz.net/responsive-wordpress-portfolio-themes-2014/

**20 WordPress Themes To Revamp Your Site For 2015**
http://designposts.net/best-free-responsive-premium-wordpress-themes-2015/